# Why did Ubuntu switch to GDM over lightDM

Tags: lightdm, gdm

I understand that both `gdm` and `lightdm` are Display Managers but I'm sincerely confused about why Canonical decided to switch Ubuntu over to `gdm` instead of the original `lightdm`?. I believe they switched because of Open Source related issues...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Because lightdm does not support wayland.

Comment: @Panther it looks like wayland is just to support 3D. Why is 3d support needed for a desktop, shouldn't layers and alpha channels be enough? Guess I'm just a little frustrated about the desktop experience taking a step backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because lightdm does not yet support wayland.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1632772

They are working on a solution and my consider switching back to lightdm in future releases.